# jQuery/CSS text-shadow effect

Tags: jquery, css

Yes, I was trying to find something before I asked.

I am working on my website and I decided to use text-shadow, t\it sounds simple but it isn't.

IE doesnt support the text-shadow property, but I want to make it cross browser so I want a jQuery plugin, but I couldn't find a working plugin that supports IE. I would like it to support IE 6+, but I can compromise and have it only support IE 7+.

I don't want a plugin that duplicates the text. For example, when you highlight the text, copy and paste you see the same word/sentence many times. I want a plugin that can make it with layers (z-index) and will work in any condition.

Thanks.

Comment: You should refrain from starting with a line in all caps that makes it sound like you're preemptively yelling at potentially answerers before they have even read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some info on mimicking `text-shadow` in a slightly simpler way in IE can be found at http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-text-shadow-ie/

However, as they say:

> But in many cases, you’d be better off not using a filter or any kind
>   of script. Let IE see a lesser experience, and save the good stuff for
>   the better browsers.
>
> Also, even though the IE filters are not loading up any extra scripts,
>   they still have performance issues and can slow the rendering of the
>   page. So again, if you can avoid them, then do so.

Comment: IE6 doesnt support css3 and It didnt work for me > filter: glow(color=red,strength=5);
Edit: I need to use width property to make it work, why? oO

Comment: I'm not sure. Try replacing your `width` property with `zoom: 1`. This will tell us if it's a hasLayout bug. Use zoom if you can as it won't restrict anything.